# copy +,, not working as expected: file is touched but also copied

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

In the pre-build event, VS2017, I added the following lines to "touch" my program so it would compile and get the date/time of compilation for my "build info" that is shown in my about infobox.

```
copy /b "$(ProjectDir)\MyAbout.cs"+,,
echo %date% %time% > "$(ProjectDir)\Resources\BuildDate.txt"
```

This has been working perfectly but I noticed I have a copy of "MyAbout.cs" in the binary directory where the executable resides.  I was under the impression that the copy would not take place if no arguments were supplied.

Windows 10

Comment: I would suggest editing the tags on this to `batch-file` or `cmd`, given that the code isn't C#.

Comment: Thx.  BTW, is there a better way to get compilation time into a C# program like a compiler directive that has the date and time and do a token paste?

Comment: There's no part of C# as a language itself to do that, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is copied instead of touched if the destination directory does not match the source directory. The default destination is the current directory.

The solution is simple:

```
copy /b "$(ProjectDir)\MyAbout.cs"+,, "$(ProjectDir)"
```

or

```
pushd "$(ProjectDir)"
copy /b MyAbout.cs+,,
popd
```